# Counting program for fibonacci sequence Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, fibonacci

I think what I am trying to do is display a select section from a defined list.  Currently this is what I am working with:

```
#fibonacci sequence algorithm, user stops by either 
#entering a maximum Fibonacci value not to exceed or
#a total count that the sequence of numbers must not
#exceed. Use a loop that allows User to repeat program
#as much as they wish, asking if they would like to 
#repeat the program each time. Validate that User input
#is either a yes or a no and only allow User to continue
#once a correct response has been given.
import array

array.listOfFibSeq = ['0','1','1','2','3','5','8','13','21','34','55','89','144','...']
startingNumber = ''
endingNumber = ''
continueYes = ''

def getStartingNumber():
    print('Please enter a valid starting number of the Fibonacci Sequence')
    print(listOfFibSeq)
    startingNumber = input()

def getEndingNumber():
    print('Please enter a valid ending number the the Fibonacci Sequence')
    print(listOfFibSeq)
    endingNumber = input()
```

I'm unsure of how to go about this, but I believe I'm trying to display (for example) 3 through 89 in the Fibonacci sequence or do something like:

```
lsitOfFibSeq.remove(<3) and listOfFibSeq.remove(>89)
```

or should I try to display a range of the Fib Sequence with a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reasonable way to precompute the fibonacci sequence before the user enters a range — you should do this dynamically.

A naive approach would be to have a function that computes the sequence for a given `(a, b)`, all the way to `end`, discarding everything up to `start`.

I prefer the generator approach:

```
import itertools
def fib():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

# Print the first 10 values of the sequence
for i in itertools.islice(fib(), 0, 10):
    print(i)
```

Or, in your case, something like:

```
start = input('Start index: ')
end = input('End index: ')

for i in itertools.islice(fib(), int(start), int(end)):
    print(i)
    if input('Continue [y/n]: ').rstrip() == 'n':
        break
```